# How can I call one constructor of partial class in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have multiple constructors and I would like to to call one constructor that have parameters , how can I do that?

**My UserControl :**

```
  public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public UserControl1(string name)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Console.WriteLine(name);  
        textbox1.Text = name;


    }
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 us = new UserControl1("John");

    }

}
```

I made a breakpoints on `UserControl1` construct that contains parameters and I saw that the the App startup called the constructor with parameters and than return to the other default constructor.
What's the reason?

Comment: Are you using your `UserControl1` anywhere in a XAML file?  If yes, then the Framework will call the default constructor.

Comment: Yes , it's WPF `UserControl` , so it have a csharp code behind and a XAML file

Comment: Are you using the user control somewhere else, for example in XAML? Try to remove the default constructor. It it crashes, you need to find where you are instantiating it using the default constructor. Your `OnStartup` method only uses the non-default constructor that accepts a `string` argument.

Comment: Yes If I delete the default constructor, the application crashes and give an Exception . the constructor called in Xaml file.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, did you check app.xaml file because there is probably xaml code which tries to open and show UserControl1 like:

```
StartupUri="UserControl1.xaml"
```

If that case, you need to delete it and show UserControl1 in OnStartup function.

Secondly, are you sure that there isn't any other UserControl1 in your project? If there is, have you ever tried to use namespace? Like:

```
SolutionName.ProjectName.UserControl1 us = new SolutionName.ProjectName.UserControl1("John");
```

Thirdly, does the program read `textbox1.Text = name;` line then goes to default constructor section to read? Could you please give more detail about it and your namespaces?

Comment: Firstly : Yes , I checked it and it contains StartupUri and I have deleted it . Secondly : I don't have a namespace and it called , Thirdly : The program read `textbox1.Text = name;` and than return to the first constructor.